# pressure difference across injection and extraction in soil

Tags: pressure, injection, porous-medium

We have a tank of dimension 100cm *100cm *5 cm( assuming 1D flow) which is filled with saturated sand and 5 cm of water standing above the soil. We inject fluid ( which is same as water in density and viscosity) using pump ( constant volume pumping) from one end and extract from other end. We have couple of pressure transducer (Integrated Silicon Pressure Sensor) to measure the pressure inside the soil all at the same level.
My question is should not there be head difference at the inlet and outlet when I am pumping with constant discharge and extraction is constant head. ( because there is flow or flow is due to head difference)
There are 6 pressure transducer at same height from inlet to outlet and all of them measure same pressure when there is flow or no flow, indicating that there is no head differnce. The discharge rate is very small i.e., 1.5L/hr ( 2.65 cm/hr velocity).
Can anyone please help on this one, this is project I am doing in my university.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your flow rate is not enough to drive a significant pressure drop in the tank.  1.5L/hr is a drip rate.

Comment: Had the rate been higher. Would the (Integrated Silicon Pressure Sensor) piezoresistive transducer show the pressure difference, considering it open channel flow? I doubt if piezoresistive transducer measures only the hydrostatic pressure (pressure due to weight) in the open channel no matter how much the flow is. Am I correct?